# How do I save a onclick html() text to LocalStorage?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a button that when a div is clicked a text is printed on another div. I want this text to be saved to local storage. I've tried this:

```
$(".light.theme").click(function(){
$('.current-theme').html("Light is active");
localStorage.content = $('.current-theme').html();
$('.current-theme').html(localStorage.content);
});
```

But its not working. Can you help?

This is my "virgin" code:

```
<div class="current-theme">Default is active</div>
<div class="light theme">Light</div>

$(".light.theme").click(function(){
    $(".current-theme").html("Light is active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save to localStorage you need to write like this.

`window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`

So in your case you need to do this

```
<div class="current-theme">Default is active</div>
<div class="light theme">Light</div>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".light.theme").click(function(){
        $(".current-theme").html("Light is active");
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', "Light")
    });
    var theme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if(theme && theme != '') {
        $(".current-theme").html(theme+" is active");
    }  

})
```

And to get back the saved value from local storage you need to do this.
`window.localStorage.getItem('theme')`

Comment: Can you correct my attempt? I could not, I got lost in the script. https://jsfiddle.net/eg3fcyr6/3/

Comment: It works already, I can see the local srorage getting updated. you jsfiddle script is fine

Comment: Are u sure? Here when I refresh the page the "default is active" is there again...

Comment: see my answer again, i updated it, you need to check for the value in local storage and then update accordingly, it wont happen automatically

Comment: hey. i am suing ur paytm package. i have done evrythng as u said. but wen i click the pay now button the page shows "transaction being processed" and then redirects me to a blank page like payment/api/status. why is it not taking me to paytm website? – Zubair Nazer Oliyat 12 secs ago